# Arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

What do we mean by a variety being arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay? Is every such variety also Gorenstein?

Comment: Determinental varieties (whose defining ideal is genenerated by minors of a matrix) are ACM but usually not Gorenstein.

Answer (score 5):

Arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay means, depending on the source/context, either:

1. The homogeneous coordinate ring (with respect to a given embedding into $\mathbb{P}^n$) is Cohen-Macaulay.  This seems to be more common.
2. The section ring (with respect to a given ample line bundle) of the variety is Cohen-Macaulay.

Of course if you are projectively normal in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and the ample line bundle is a very ample line bundle of that embedding, these two definitions coincide.

It doesn't imply anything about Gorenstein-ness.   In fact, any *Cohen-Macaulay* projective variety with $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = 0$ for $0 < i < \dim X$ is arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay with respect to some embedding into projective space.

To see this, take a sufficiently ample line bundle $L$ such that $H^i(X, \omega_X \otimes L^n) = 0$ and $H^i(X, L^n) = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$ and all $0 < i < \dim X$.  In the previous version of this answer, I forgot the Cohen-Macaulay hypothesis on $X$, in which case the first vanishing can't be forced to hold.

If I recall correctly, these notions appear prominently in the study of Linkage (see Eisenbud's book for an introduction).

A related notion is that of arithmetic Macaulayfication of a ring.  This means that there exists an ideal $I$ such that the Rees algebra of $I$ (the ring you blow-up to get the blow-up of $I$) is Cohen-Macaulay.  These were shown to exist in the last decade by Kawasaki.  If I recall correctly, a corollary of this result is that every ring with a dualizing complex is a quotient of a Gorenstein ring (this was previously a conjecture of Sharp).  Someone correct me if I'm wrong on this.

EDIT:  Added the CM hypothesis on the variety and added an explanation (thanks to Long).
EDIT2:  Added the two possible definitions (section ring vs coordinate ring).  Thanks to J. C. Ottem.

Comment: A stupid question: When $X$ is projectively normal under the embedding given by $L$, the section ring $A=\bigoplus_{n\ge 0}H^0(X,L^n)$ is isomorphic to the coordinate ring $S(X)$ of X under this embedding. In general $A$ can be regarded as a $S(X)$-module. When $X$ is not projectively normal, is there any essential difference between ACM and $S(X)$ being CM?

Comment: Karl, don't you need the middle cohomology of all the  twists to vanish? 

Comment: @Ottem. Can you give an easy example when the section ring fails to be the same as the coordinate ring? Is the issue that the section ring might not be generated in degree 1? My feeling is that in this case, what one really cares about is the section ring, not the coordinate ring, and that the coordinate ring is losing some (stacky) information.

Comment: @Ottem. They are different. Take $\mathbb P^1$ embedded in $\mathbb P^4$ by $x^4$, $x^3y$, $xy^3$, $y^4$. This is a closed immersion, but not projectively normal. The section ring is Cohen-Macaulay, but the homogeneous coordinate ring is not, because it is regular in codimension 1, but not normal and therefore not S2.

@Pascal. It is the section ring which is losing information. In the example above, the section ring doesn't distinguish between the given embedding and the embedding by all sections of $\mathcal O(4)$.

Comment: @Long, all the middle twists vanish by Serre vanishing and Serre duality.  Just take a very high veronese subring.

Comment: In light of Dustin's nice example, I find this definition a little strange, since Eisenbud's definition of ACM is just that the coordinate ring is CM. Thus I'd think that you'd have to require that the variety should be projectively normal in it's embedding for this to work (or equivalently, the vanishing of $H^i(\mathbb{P}^n,I_X(t))$ for $0<i<dim X$.)

Comment: @J.C. Ottem, I'm happy to be wrong here.  I'm not sure which is the more common usage.  I have seen papers where it is just the section ring that is CM, and not the coordinate ring.  I'll put a comment in saying this.

Comment: @J. C. Ottem, I think you are right, the coordinate ring definition is much more common. Before posting the original answer, I found some places where it was defined the other way, and went with that. But I probably should not have